# I want to use the invoke-restmethod in a foreach loop to upload a multiplefiles through Infile parameter

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs, invoke-command

Each time the loop executes the file is being replaced in the place of the first file . I want to upload it as a new file without distrubing the existing ones..

```
foreach ($blob in $blobs)
{   
    $file=New-TemporaryFile
    $file=Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $container_name -Blob $blob.Name -Context $ctx -Destination $localFile -Force
    $contents = Get-Content $localFile -Raw -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
    $f=New-TemporaryFile
    Add-Content $f $contents
    $Header = @{
"Content-Disposition"="attachment;filename=$($blob.Name)"
"Authorization"=$accessToken
        }
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $Header  -Method put -InFile $f 


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you over-did it with the `New-TemporaryFile` commands in your code.
Why use `Get-AzureStorageBlobContent` to store blob content in a file and then create another temp file to copy the contents to?

This would be much simpler:

```
foreach ($blob in $blobs) {  
    $localFile = New-TemporaryFile
    Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $container_name -Blob $blob.Name -Context $ctx -Destination $localFile.FullName -Force

    $Header = @{
        "Content-Disposition"="attachment;filename=$($blob.Name)"
        "Authorization"=$accessToken
    }

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $Header  -Method put -InFile $localFile.FullName
}
```

**Edit**

The `New-TemporaryFile` command returns a `System.IO.FileInfo` object which you cannot use directly as the `InFile` parameter. Instead, it expects a full path and file name, so we use `$localFile.FullName`